# Can OpenGL render two Qt panels together?

Tags: qt, opengl

I have a Qt application, the main window has two panels, one is a customized `QWidget` which uses *OpenGL* to draw the content, and the other is a `QWebEngineView` which I newly added. My problem is when this `QWebEngineView` loads Url, the other `QWidget` won't show the content.

I searched that `QWebEngineView` also uses *OpenGL* to render the web page, I'm wondering whether it's because of some conflicts of *OpenGL*. Can't *OpenGL* render two panels together? If so, is there any way to solve this? For the customized `QWidget`, it has to use *OpenGL*, so is there any workaround I can do for the `QWebEngineView`?

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL renders using the current context. Each panel may have its own context.

While you can have several windows with the same context, and render to a window just by associating the context to that window, QWebEngineView will use its own context (you don't know it).

Just refresh your own window and render to it.

Comment: So do you mean that because my QWidget and QWebEngineView have different openGL contexts. One should be rendered after the other finished rendering? Then if there are multiple openGL contexts, how it's determined which one is the current one?

Comment: A window must be re-drawn when it needs it. Normally you do rendering on your 'paint' event. You can force a paint event by calling `update()`. You can set a contex as current calling, for example, `wglMakeCurrent` (Windows only) or if using QOpenGLContext calling `makeCurrent`

Comment: Thanks for answering! Sorry I'm pretty new to all these. So by saying "window" you mean QWidget? And when calling `update()` of a window, will the OpenGL context for this window be set as current context automatically? And also want to ask, instead of setting, how to get current OpenGL context?

Comment: No "automagically". Windows get current: [msdn wglGetCurrentContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/dd374383(v=vs.85).aspx).